# Delete Text in a textfield

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have got a problem and I don't have any idea how to solve it.
I use Selenium2Library with Robot Framework IDE for webtesting and I have a textfield with text in it. This text I like to delete and put another Text in the field. 
I tried to use the "Press Key" Keyword like this.

```
Press Key    locater of the textfield    \\1    (ctrl+a to mark everything)
Press Key    locater of the textfield    \\127  (del to delete the text)
```

The first Keyword do nothing and the second deletes one letter.

Does anybody know how to solve my problem?

Thank you for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
Input Text <locater of the textfield> ${EMPTY}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does answers the question. The solution provided should work! If you are new to Robot framework, please refer this link: http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.8#Input%20Text

Answer (score 1):

Try:
Press Keys (locator)CTRL+a+BACKSPACE

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this to delete the text from object in ROBOTFRAMEWORK  This may help you.

for Delete
Press Keys         ${LocatorToInputText}         \DELETE

for Tab

Press Keys        ${LocatorToInputText}        \TAB

for Enter

Press Keys        ${LocatorToInputText}        yourdata+RETURN

script is tab or 4 space seperated